# Edit first column of csv with sed or awk in bash

Tags: awk, sed, osx, csv

I have a csv file and want to edit just the first column containing title of scientific papers by deleting everything after the ";" sign.

So a typical title would have the following form:

```
long scientific title here;other stuff I want to delete including the semicolon (no space between ; and the text)
```

I want the title to look like this:

```
long scientific title here
```

How can I achieve that using either `sed` or `awk` (on macOS if this matters)?

Comment: do u want to delete all after the first semicolon in each row?

Comment: Just edited my question.

Comment: So if `long scientific title here` appears more than once you want to modify the first row it occurs in but leave any following rows alone entirely right?

Comment: Hi Jesse, I would like all titles in the first column to be treated the same way, so that everything behind a semicolon is removed. Not all titles have a ; but the vast majority does.

Comment: I gather your column separator is tab.

Comment: In that case I think @freddy should undelete their answer.

Comment: @Jesse_b Undeleted. But I'm not sure if that's what OP really wants.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to remove everything after the first semicolon in each row:

With `cut`:

```
cut -d';' -f1 file
```

- `-d';'` use semicolon as delimiter
- `-f1` print the first field

---

With `awk`:

```
awk -F';' '{ print $1 }' file
```

Similar to `cut`: Use semicolon as input field separator and print the first field.

---

With `sed`:

```
sed 's/;.*//' file
```

Substitute semicolon and any following characters with an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

As it is the first column I think (GNU) sed is enough. Assuming that the column separators are tabs:

```
sed -E 's/^(.*);.*\t/\1\t/' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Your OS contains many small and simple tools that do text processing. In this case I would use `cut` :

```
cut -d; -f1 <FILE >tmpfile && mv tmpfile FILE
```